# Wilcoxon sign rank test in R does not match with GraphPad Prism

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am comparing several combinations of two columns of non-normally distributed paired data:

[image]

I used R with the following syntax:
wilcox.test(x, y, paired=T)

I tried to replicate this test in GraphPad Prism using Wilcoxon matched pairs signed rank test with or without the method of Pratt.
[image]
[image]

The obtained p-values do not match:

[image]

None of these p-values is corrected for multiple testing (yet).
Any ideas what could be the reason for the discrepancy?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's hard to tell why without access to the data...

Comment: What results do you get? Hos different are they?